# vertical text orientation (multiple rows) in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I would like to create a table that is labelled like the axis of a plot, i.e. a vertical orientation of the y-axis' label. This is what I have

```
\begin{tabular}{rc|c|c|c|}
&&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Category A}\\
&&little&some&a lot\\
&little&&&\\
Category B&some&&\\
&a lot&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

But I would like the text 'Category B', to be vertical spanning from row 3-5 instead of being horizontal in row 4.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: have a look at [rotate+table+labels](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=rotate+table+labels), it seems like there are quite a few questions that have dealt with similar issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Depending on exactly what you need, you may wish to adjust the spacing, but something like this:

Here I have added extra `\hline` to the table to make the spacing clearer, also the heading is backspaced by the depth of a table row so that it exactly fits (The first version got this wrong) this spacing may be adjusted in individual cases to gain better visual spacing if that is needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newsavebox\zzz
\def\mystrut{%
\dimen@\wd\zzz
\divide\dimen@\thr@@
\advance\dimen@-\dp\@arstrutbox
\rule\z@\dimen@}

\def\rotatezzz{%
\rotatebox{90}{\rlap{\kern-\dp\@arstrutbox\usebox\zzz}}}

\makeatother
\begin{document}




\savebox\zzz{Category B}
\begin{tabular}{rc|c|c|c|}
&&\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Category A}\\
&&little&some&a lot\\\hline
\mystrut&little&&&\\
\mystrut&some&&&\\
\mystrut\rotatezzz&a lot&&&\\\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Is there a way to measure the width of the rotated box and give each of the last 3 rows 1/3 of that as height? And then to  vertically center the text in those rows?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Nice, applied that to all tables! Imagine 'Category B' is 'Category LongName'. Is it possible to get something like `\savebox\zzz{Category\\LongName}`? Also is the vertical text closer to the bottom of the last than to the top of the first row. Can that be centred?

Comment: as always with savebox if you want multiple lines you need to put it in a parbox (or better here a tabular as then you can still measure so `\savebox\zzz{\begin{tabular}{l}Category\\ LongName\end{tabular}}`   you can use `\rlap{\hspace{10pt}\usebox\zzz}` to raise it a bit, you need to choose the value by eye.... centering row spans automatically is tricky unless you re-implement almost all of latex table internals

Comment: The arithmetic in that mystrut is nonsense I will update in a bit (I am adding not subtracting for a start: you should do what I meant not what I wrote:-)