# Table with rotated headings on fixed height rows

Tags: tables, spacing, rotating

I am trying to create a 2 x 2 table with centered headings.  The row headings need to be rotated as shown below (mocked-up in another program).  The cells are supposed to be 1in tall and 1.4in wide.

[image: Example to table]

What I get instead is the following.  The height of the parbox seems to have been added to the cell height.  I have tried correcting this with `\raisebox` and `\strut` and `\rule` to no avail:

[image: Example of table]

My code currently looks like this:

```
\begin{supertabular}{c | p{1.4in} | p{1.4in} |}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Full} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Partial} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \raisebox{-1in}[0in][0in]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{1in}{\centering Shutdown}}} & {Pellentesque enim mi, ornare in blandit quis, dignissim ut velit. Etiam tempus tortor quam.} & {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a lorem sed dui aliquam feugiat eget at arcu.} \\[1in]
    \cline{2-3}
    \raisebox{-1in}[0in][0in]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{1in}{\centering Active}}} & {Pellentesque convallis scelerisque libero, eu gravida metus porttitor nec. Nulla facilisi.} & {Sed auctor nibh at purus mattis porta. Nunc vitae ante lacus.} \\[1in]
    \cline{2-3}
\end{supertabular}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: @NeilSteiner You're welcome. It does not solve your problem, but for your information, the command `\\[1in]` will add a 1 inch space between the 2 rows of your table, as you can see on your attempt

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Lionel's comment, and some extra digging, I found that the following works:

```
\newlength{\height}
\setlength{\height}{1in}
\newlength{\pointsevenbaselineskip}
\setlength{\pointsevenbaselineskip}{0.7\baselineskip}

\begin{supertabular}{c @{\rule[-\height+\pointsevenbaselineskip]{0pt}{\height}~} | p{1.4in} | p{1.4in} |}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Full} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\centering Partial} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \raisebox{-\height+\pointsevenbaselineskip}[0in][0in]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{\height}{\centering Shutdown}}} 
        & \small{Pellentesque enim mi, ornare in blandit quis, dignissim ut velit. Etiam tempus tortor quam.} 
        & \small{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin a lorem sed dui aliquam feugiat eget at arcu.} \\
    \cline{2-3}
    \raisebox{-\height+\pointsevenbaselineskip}[0in][0in]{\rotatebox{90}{\parbox[c]{\height}{\centering Active}}}
        & \small{Pellentesque convallis scelerisque libero, eu gravida metus porttitor nec. Nulla facilisi.} 
        & \small{Sed auctor nibh at purus mattis porta. Nunc vitae ante lacus.} \\
    \cline{2-3}
\end{supertabular}
```

I'm not sure why even with the calc package, `-\height+\pointsevenbaselineskip` works, but `-\height+0.7\baselineskip` does not.

This approach is non-ideal if the row height isn't fixed (mine isn't, despite the way I posed the question), but I can `\setlength{\height}{...}` on a per-row basis if necessary.  If someone can offer a better solution, particularly if it provides a way to infer the cell height and center automatically, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: Would it be helpul: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52389/vertical-text-orientation-multiple-rows-in-tabular-environment ?

Comment: @maria, thanks for the suggestion.  I just tried that, but it doesn't vertically center the heading with respect to the cell parbox, so it doesn't help my situation.